# php extension & windows environment variable PATH

Tags: php, windows, apache, environment-variables

I just finished installed Apache2.4.2 and pHp5.4.5
Now when is stated server i get PHP startup error "Unable to load dynamic library xyz.dll for about 12 extensions. Now when I copy files from pHp directory to system32, many of these errors get removed, but I've heard of environment variables and I want to use environment variables instead of copying every file to system32.

Thanks
Varun Agrawal

Comment: And if restart is require to set environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Presuming Apache is running as Windows Service)*

The following, from [Search Order for Desktop Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications), describes the search order used to to locate a DLL:

- 1.The directory from which the application loaded.
- 2.The current directory.
- 3.The system directory. Use the `GetSystemDirectory()` function to get the path of this directory.
- 4.The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
- 5.The Windows directory. Use the `GetWindowsDirectory()` function to get the path of this directory.
- 6.The directories that are listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the `App Paths` registry key. The `App Paths` key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

By modifying the `PATH` environment variable to contain the directory in which your DLLs reside would allow them to be found. However, as Apache is running as a Windows Service not only would Apache require a restart, but the Services Control Manager would require a restart. The only way (that I know of) to restart the Services Control Manager is to reboot the machine.

---

To edit the system `PATH` environment variable (on XP anyway):

- Right-click on `My Computer` and select `Properties`
- Select the `Advanced` tab in the `System Properties` dialog that appears
- Click on the `Environment Variables` button
- Locate `PATH` in the `System variables` list
- Click `Edit` and add your directory